# Can the fact that debt is being collected be disclosed under Australian Consumer Law and Fair Trading Act 2012 section 45(j)

Tags: privacy, australia, debt, victoria

The Act states:
"disclosing or threatening to disclose debt
information, without the consent of the
debtor, to any other person who does not
have a clear and legitimate interest in the
information;
Example
Disclosing debt information when contacting a person
who is not the debtor while attempting to locate or
identify the debtor"

So if I attempt to call a debtors old work place can I disclose that I am searching for him because I am collecting a debt without further information or should I say that I am prohibited by disclosing my reason for making contact with the individual by  the Australian Consumer Law and Fair Trading Act 2012 section 45(j) - (which is pretty much saying that I believe that he is a debtor).

Answer (score 3):

The Australian government has put out a document entitled [RG 96 Debt Collection Guideline](https://asic.gov.au/regulatory-resources/find-a-document/regulatory-guides/rg-96-debt-collection-guideline-for-collectors-and-creditors).  It makes it clear that they consider it forbidden to disclose that you are collecting a debt.  They even forbid disclosures that would allow a third party to *infer* that you are collecting a debt. Part 2, Section 1(b):

> If you consider it necessary to divulge your identity as a debt collector before being sure that you
> are dealing with the debtor (for example, if requested by the person you are dealing with), then
> you may do so **if that would not have the effect of divulging that the debtor has a debt**. Particular
> care should be taken when speaking to a person at a debtor’s workplace or when using a medium
> that may be shared with others (e.g. social media, landline telephones etc).

Section 8:

> Telling any third party the reason for trying to find the debtor will also disclose
> personal information about the debtor.

> Caution should be exercised when leaving messages for the debtor that may be seen or accessed
> by third parties, for example:
> Business cards or other documentation should not be left for the debtor in any open manner
> that would allow a third party to infer the nature of your interest in contacting the debtor. Voicemail messages should be phrased so as to avoid a third party inferring the nature of your
> interest in contacting the debtor. At no stage should contact be made with a debtor’s social media account that would
> compromise the debtor’s privacy, for example, placing a message for the debtor in a way that
> would allow anyone other than the debtor to view it.

So to your questions:

> So if I attempt to call a debtors old work place can I disclose that I am searching for him because I am collecting a debt without further information

No, you cannot not say that.

> or should I say that I am prohibited by disclosing my reason for making contact with the individual by the Australian Consumer Law and Fair Trading Act 2012 section 45(j)

You should not say that either, as it would allow the former employer to infer the nature of your interest in contacting the debtor.